# How do I define json writer for custom object in Play + Scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Could you please demostrate how I can define json writer for my class in Scala and Play Framework 2.1-RC2 ?

The documentation is quite confusing (and will be significant obstacle for wider adoption of Scala/Play by web-developer community). For example not only it's unclear where exactly following code (taken from **[here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJsonCombinators)**) should be located

```
implicit val taskWrites = (
  (__ \ "id").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "label").write[Boolean] ~
)(unlift(Task.unapply))
```

but it's also not compilable if I put it inside `object` definition. Play gives me following error

```
not found: value __
```

Here is my Task.scala

http://pastebin.com/hG8F6Gqk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turned out the problem was obvious. I forgot to import `play.api.libs.functional.syntax._`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

Answer (score -1):

The underscore you're using isn't a standard underscore.

Your underscore: __

ASCII Character #95: _